# Is it safe to access GUI elements from Task.onSucceeded()?

Tags: asynchronous, javafx-2, task

I am using a `Task` to do some calculations, the output of this calculation is stored as a String. When the calculation is done, the output shall be shown in a `TextArea`. Is it safe to use Task's [`onSucceeded`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty) for settings the `TextArea`'s text? If not, what's the best / recommended way to wait until the task has finished and then write the output to the `TextArea`?

Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see quote from  `Task` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html):

> Because the Task is designed for use with JavaFX GUI applications, it ensures that every change to its public properties, as well as change notifications for state, errors, and for event handlers, all occur on the main JavaFX application thread.

You can verify such cases yourself using next code:

```
task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
```

Output should be:

> JavaFX Application Thread

Comment: ah cool, wasn't aware of that I can check this so easy. For me the task description isn't totally clear, because of "change notification for event handler", I am missing a clear "task events are executed on the app. thread".

Comment: Also you can use Platform.isFXApplicationThread() to check the same thing: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isFxApplicationThread()